# Operation timed out in xmlhttp.Send in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am fetching data from website. It was working my laptop till last week without any trouble anytime, All of the sudden, it started to give strange behavior(It works in evening and it fail to work during day time. Can anyone please look into below sample code and let me know the reason?

```
Sub FailedTest2()
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    'Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") ' I tried this also
    URL = "http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=HDFCBANK&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=26DEC2019"
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", URL, False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/JSON"
    xmlhttp.Send
    MsgBox xmlhttp.responseText
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run the following command and see what happened?

    curl -H 'Content-Type: text/JSON' 'http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=HDFCBANK&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=26DEC2019'

Comment: @Popeye Thanks Bro!, Its working now. Any explanation would be much appreciated!, why it worked before without this modification ( xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type:", "text/JSON" )

Comment: @Popeye sorry, It is again not working, it was working in the evening with and without change as I mentioned above, All of sudden, its not working during Market Hour, whereas It worked in the evening time.....any suggestion ?

Comment: I made following changes to IE, Its working again. internet options > security tab > custom security level > Miscellaneous >Access data sources across domains > enable

Comment: I think there is issue with the server itself. If you go to the page using URL that you have posted, You will see a html Page. So, I am wondering if the server itself stable or not